# PHP destruct function show an error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an error shown in the destruct function in my class which connects to the data base, I tried to remove the variable in the destruct function but also it shows an error. Here is the code:

```
class DB_CONNECT {
    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
        echo "connected succesfully";
    }
    function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect() {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) 
                or die(mysqli_error());
        if($con){
            echo "connected succesfully";
        }
        return $con;
    }

    function close() {
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

and there is the error message:

> mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: I think you're going to have to post some more code, for instance the class and how the functions are defined, where `$con` is coming from etc.

Comment: Yeah, definitely need more code.

Comment: write full error message

Comment: Error would be helpful, but probably `mysqli_close($this->con);`

Comment: How would the `close()` function know what `$con` is ?

Comment: but also i tried this mysqli_close(), and also shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connect method you are not assigning the `mysqli` object to a instance variable.

In `__destruct` `$con` is undefined/NULL this explains the error message.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

class DB_CONNECT {
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect() {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) 
                          or die(mysqli_error());
        echo "connected succesfully";
    }

    function close() {
        mysqli_close($this->conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: but also i tried this mysqli_close(), and also shows the same error, i think that mysqli_close close every connection opened

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, all mysqli handles in a process that connect to the same DB share a connection , so yes I think you are correct. I would remove `mysqli_close($this->conn);` and let the connection be closed automatically when the process dies.

Answer (score 0):

`$con` needs to be accessible everywhere so assign it as an object var `$this->con`:

```
function connect() {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());
    if($this->con){
        echo "connected succesfully";
    }
    return $this->con;
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->close();
}


function close() {
    mysqli_close($this->con);
}
```